# Given an array of datetimes in the past, what is a good method to shuffle them all forward to a minimum specific datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have an array of objects for events, things that happened in the past.  They can be relatively vast, and for testing reasons, I need them to be in the future.

- Object1) StartTime = 7/2/2022 @ 8:00amEST
- Object2) StartTime = 7/2/2022 @ 9:00amEST
- Object3) StartTime = 7/4/2022 @ 3:00pmEST
- Object4) StartTime = 7/4/2022 @ 3:30pmEST
- Object5) StartTime = 7/5/2022 @ 10:00amEST
- ... etc.

I need to shuffle these times to be based on a date in the future, so much as even `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);`

I've tried multiple times, but always botch things like having the wrong month, or ending up with a datetime on the 32nd.

The output of this method would take the dates and revise as so:

- Object1) StartTime = 11/22/2022 @ 8:00amEST
- Object2) StartTime = 11/22/2022 @ 9:00amEST
- Object3) StartTime = 11/24/2022 @ 3:00pmEST
- Object4) StartTime = 11/24/2022 @ 3:30pmEST
- Object5) StartTime = 11/25/2022 @ 10:00amEST

```
DateTime CreateDateFromTime(int year, int month, int day, DateTime time)
{
        return new DateTime(year, month, day, time.Hour, time.Minute, 0);
}   


for (int i = 0; i < evt.Sessions.Count; i++)
{
    Session session = evt.Sessions[i];
    if (session.StartDate.HasValue)
    {
        DateTime currentSessionStartDate = session.StartDate.Value;
        DateTime currentSessionEndDate = session.EndDate.Value;
        if (earliestSessionDay == 0) { earliestSessionDay = currentSessionStartDate.Day; }
        int innerOffset = currentSessionStartDate.Day - earliestSessionDay;
        int offset = DateTime.Now.Day - earliestSessionDay;
        session.StartDate = CreateDateFromTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + offset + innerOffset + 5, currentSessionStartDate);

        session.EndDate = CreateDateFromTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + offset + innerOffset + 5, currentSessionEndDate);
    }
}
```

I would have mocked dates, but again, for testing reasons, the test users want to use data they are familiar with so we end up reusing these objects, thus necessitating this weird date shift thing.

Comment: [*Noda Time*](https://nodatime.org/)

Comment: Shuffle implies randomnesss. There doesn't seem to be any randomness in the code you've provided.

Comment: Vernacular.  Shuffle as in "move forward", not randomize.

Comment: @CarComp - Perhaps look up the meaning of shuffle. It doesn't mean "move forward".

Comment: Perhaps. Every day I'm shuffling.

Comment: @Enigmativity [shuffle](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shuffle) - "To act in a shifty or deceitful manner" - that looks exactly what OP wants to do - grab some values and pretend they happen at different times (aka "cook books") :)

Comment: I haved no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what I think you need:

```
DateTime[] dates = new []
{
    new DateTime(2022, 7, 2, 8, 0, 0),
    new DateTime(2022, 7, 2, 9, 0, 0),
    new DateTime(2022, 7, 2, 15, 0, 0),
};

DateTime minimum = dates.Min();

TimeSpan delta = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0).Subtract(minimum);

DateTime[] forwarded =
    dates.Select(d => d.Add(delta)).ToArray();
```

[image: forwarded]

If you want to preserve the times, then use `.Date` like this:

```
DateTime minimum = dates.Min().Date;

TimeSpan delta = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1.0).Subtract(minimum);
```

Comment: Astounding answer

Comment: @CarComp - How so?

Comment: Shuffles all the dates forward :)

Comment: Is there a way to preserve time?  I noticed that when i ran it, time math between the original time and possibly the `DateTime.Now` clock caused all of the times on the dates to be off by 3 minutes.  It still works well enough to use, but its an oddity.

Comment: @CarComp - I have already provided a way to preserve the original times and only shift the dates. I even said "preserve the times".